# Pistes de traduction du « one-trick pony » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, langage-informel

En anglais on a le « one-trick pony » ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one-trick%20pony), [Wik.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one-trick_pony), [Brit.](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/one%E2%80%93trick-pony), [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/idiom/one-trick-pony/)), informel, dont on dit par exemple qu'il est « one that is skilled in only one area; also : one that has success only once  » (MW), donc quelqu'un dont la qualité en question est réduite à une seule chose ou à une seule fois. Par exemple on trouve sur *Learners (Britannica)*:

> As a knitter, I'm a *one-trick pony*: I can only knit scarves. [seule
> chose]
>  [A] musician who was a *one-trick pony* and then faded away.
> [seule fois]

Ou la référence directe au sens à l'origine (le cirque) de cette expression idiomatique du début du 20e siècle :

> He's a one-trick pony / One trick is all that horse can do / He does
> one trick only / It's the principal source of his revenue. (Paul
> Simon)

A-t-on une expression passe-partout équivalente et est-elle grammaticalement différente ou comment va-t-on s'y prendre pour traduire ce genre de phrase et pense-t-on employer les mêmes tournures dans un grand nombre de contextes distincts et a-t-on quelques exemples ?

Answer (score 8):

Pour exprimer le contraire, on dira *il a plus d'une corde à son arc* donc, logiquement, on peut aussi dire :

> ***Il n'a qu'une corde à son arc.***

Sinon, un peu plus proche du ***trick*** mais de sens plus éloigné :

> ***Il n'a qu'un tour dans son sac.***

Pas facile cependant de placer ces expressions quand on parle de couture ou de musique...

Selon le contexte, on pourra aussi trouver:

> ***C'est l'homme d'un seul succès.*** (aussi, *d'un seul **livre***, *d'un seul **tube***, *d'un seul **film***...)

Comment: Ce musicien n'a fait qu'un tube. Ce peintre n'a fait qu'une exposition,  ce couturier n'a fait qu'un défilé

Comment: @Personne Oui, ***C'est l'homme d'un seul succès***.

Comment: — Un musicien qui n'a *fait/joué* qu'une seule tournée, un seul spectacle/concert — 
Un artiste qui n'a *produit* qu'une seule œuvre … *Merci Deepl* :-)

Comment: @Personne Deepl est très premier-degré sur ce coup là: ***a one-trick pony*** → **un poney à un coup** 

Comment: Vous remarquerez, cher M. (le champion toutes catégories du site !! + :-), que l'abstinence librement choisie peut manifester mon estime pour ce site qui corrige souvent plus finement les documents français déposés dans le cadre de gauche que tous les autres correcteurs libres sous Linux… laissons là le poney avec le mérinos…

Comment: @Personne Il faut relativiser mon niveau de réputation. Il est pour beaucoup dû à l'abandon plus ou moins définitif de FSE par certains de ses anciens champions et le refus de la "compétition" ou les comptes multiples abandonnés/renouvelés d'autres utilisateurs. J'ai la lucidité de savoir que je suis une espèce de borgne hyperactif dans un royaume de bienveillants malvoyants. :-)

Comment: "Il n'a qu'un tour dans son sac." Jamais lu ni entendu cette expression-là pour ma part, contrairement à la classique "... plus d'un tour dans son sac". Enfin, sur l'aspect "truc qui ne marche qu'une seule fois", on a l'expression "c'est un fusil à un coup".

Comment: @XouDo C'est plus rare que *ne **pas/plus** avoir qu'un tour [...]* ou *avoir plus d'un tour [...]* mais on l'entend ou le lit quand même : *— Non, dit l’autre; je n’ai qu’un tour dans mon bissac !, Mais je soutiens qu’il en vaut mille.* La Fontaine.

Comment: Je pensais probablement à _d'un seul numéro_, est-ce que ça se dit, ça évoque sans doute plus le cirque que l'expression en anglais aujourd'hui et pas sûr que ça marche pour la « seule fois » mais bon.

Comment: @solastalgienitsyne On pourrais, mais *numéro* est bien sûr ambigu. James Bond, l'homme d'un seul numéro... le 7 !

Answer (score 3):

Je ne vois pas d'expression aussi imagée, je ferais plus banal :

> Il n'a qu'un talent

> Je ne sais faire qu'une chose

Dans le sens *"one-hit band"* :

> Ils n'ont eu qu'un succès